# Error in installation of assembly policy.9.0.Microsoft.VC90.MFC version="9.0.21022.8"

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, winsxs

I encountered this error during an installation,

> An error occurred during the installation of assembly
>   'policy.9.0.Microsoft.VC90.MFC,version="9.0.21022.8",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",
>   processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32-policy"'.

I have searched extensively for solutions, some had a similar problem but they either did not have solutions or their solutions did not work. Does anyone with experience with these assemblies know why this is happening?

For more context this was a Windows installer for a USB device firmware configuration tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the machine is too messed up to run your software then you want to know about it as soon as possible so you don't waste too much time on it.  That worked out well here, looks like the side-by-side cache turned into spaghetti.  Tell the user to re-image it.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, I guess in this case I am the user which has to re-image the side-by-side cache. I did some more research into this and came up with instructions like: 

> Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase

Though these were mostly recommended for a cleanup of the WinSxS folder in terms of size, so I'm not sure. Is this what you were referring to?